# How to set max width of GtkLabel properly?

Tags: user-interface, alignment, label, vala

I am writing a Vala application and using GtkLabels' in it. Problem is, I made my main window not resizable and when I'm adding labels with a long text to it, the window gets very big (when the window was resizable, all labels were fitting perfectly). I tried to `set_max_width_chars()` to some value and it kind of works, but I guess this isn't the right way to do it (because users' fonts may vary and this won't work with fonts sizes that are different from mine).

So, the question: how to do it the right way?

Comment: I am also curious as to how to do this; GTK appears to have a plethora of functions for setting the minimum width of something, but `set_max_width_chars()` is literally the only one I can find for setting a maximum.

Answer (score 14):

You can't directly limit the width of a label (other than `max-width-chars`, which is in characters, not in pixels), but you can limit it indirectly by influencing the size of the box that contains it and by setting 4 not immediately obvious properties of the label.

### Consider the following scenario:

- You have a box
- You have multiple subboxes with widgets in the box
- All widgets have their natural size, that size can be bigger or smaller, but it's always reasonable

*RESULT:*

- box is expanded as needed for all widgets to fit

### Now comes the label:

- There are label (maybe multiple labels) in one/some of the boxes
- Label text can be anything, including a very long string
- You didn't tell the label to wrap into multiple lines (this is the default)

*RESULT:*

- box is expanded to ridiculous width to accommodate the label (other widgets are much smaller)

### In this scenario the following fix is available:

- Set `max-width-chars` of the label to a small positive value (`1` would work just fine)
- Set `ellipsize` of the label to any value other than `PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_NONE`
- Set `hexpand` of the label to `TRUE` (or set `expand` of the label to `TRUE`, with obvious consequences)
- Set `fill` of the label (as a child of the subbox it's in) to `TRUE` (if `vexpand` is also `TRUE`, you might want to restrict its filling to horizontal direction only)

*RESULT:*

- width of the box depends only on widths of the other widgets, and is unaffected by the length of the text of the label
- the label is expanded to fill the available space (the space depends only on the width of the box, see above), regardless of how small the positive value of `max-width-chars` is
- if the label text is so long that it doesn't fit in the available space, it will be ellipsized

This works on labels and other text widgets that have `ellipsize` and `max-width-chars` (such as `GtkCellRendererText` inside a `GtkTreeView`).

Tested with GTK+-3.18.2

Comment: Unintiutive but works very well, also with GTK 2.x, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your labels should be put in containers, and the enclosing containers should be sized appropriately. If this is not useful suggestion to you, you might consider posting a screenshot to better understand your requirements.

Comment: you could try the `set_size_request` method on the Alignment: http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.set_size_request

Comment: tried to to this: `titleAlignment.add(titleLabel);
  titleAlignment.set_size_request(625, -1);
  box.add(titleAlignment);` this seems to have no effect.